# Dynamic data for PDFMake using arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfmake

So I'm very new to PDFMake and I'm looking for a way to dynamically create a table using data coming back from the DB. I'm struggling to get the data to display and I'm not sure how exactly I should go about rendering the table data in my code. Please see below the code I have and how I'm attempting to display the data:

```
dummyServiceData = [
    { serviceType: "More", service: "Company Profile", quantity: 1, price: 250, discount: 0, total: 250 },
    { serviceType: "SARS", service: "Free Expert Accounting, Tax and/or Payroll Consultation (Optional) (Valued at R200)", quantity: 1, price: 0, discount: 0, total: 0 },
    { serviceType: "More", service: "Free Official BEE Affidavit (Optional) (Valued @ R200)", quantity: 1, price: 0, discount: 0, total: 0 },
    { serviceType: "More", service: "Free Tenders-4-Me App (5 Top Tenders for You) (Optional)", quantity: 1, price: 0, discount: 0, total: 0 },
    { serviceType: "SARS", service: "Free Invoice App (Optional)", quantity: 1, price: 0, discount: 0, total: 0 },
    { serviceType: "More", service: "Company Profile", quantity: 1, price: 650, discount: 0, total: 650 },
    { serviceType: "SARS", service: "Free Expert Accounting, Tax and/or Payroll Consultation (Optional) (Valued at R200)", quantity: 1, price: 0, discount: 0, total: 0 },
    { serviceType: "More", service: "Free Official BEE Affidavit (Optional) (Valued @ R200)", quantity: 1, price: 0, discount: 0, total: 0 },
    { serviceType: "More", service: "Free Tenders-4-Me App (5 Top Tenders for You) (Optional)", quantity: 1, price: 0, discount: 0, total: 0 },
    { serviceType: "SARS", service: "Free Invoice App (Optional)", quantity: 1, price: 0, discount: 0, total: 0 },
];
let dummyUser = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", userCode: "JOHN1234", emailPrime: "john@gmail.com", numberPrime: "0798947345", vatNumber: "123456789" };

// [left, top, right, bottom] or [horizontal, vertical] or just a number for equal margins
let docDefinition = {
    pageMargins: [20, 20, 20, 40],
    styles: {
        smoll: {
            fontSize: 7,
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        },
    },
    footer: (currentPage, pageCount, pageSize) => {
        return {
            columns: [
                {
                    stack: [
                        { text: "www.companypartners.co.za", link: "www.companypartners.co.za", alignment: "center", fontSize: 9, margin: [0, 0, 0, 5] },
                        { text: "Page " + currentPage.toString() + " of " + pageCount, alignment: "center", color: "#7f7f7f", fontSize: 8 },
                    ],
                    margin: [20, 0],
                },
            ],
        };
    },
    content: [
        {
            columns: [
                {
                    margin: [10, 25, 0, 0],
                    ol: [{ height: 50, width: 200, image: logo }],
                },
                {
                    type: "none",
                    fontSize: 6,
                    margin: [50, 25, 0, 0],
                    ol: [
                        {
                            text: "Company",
                            bold: true,
                        },
                        "Reg. No: 2011/123456/01",
                        "VAT No: 4123456789",
                        "Email: accounts@company.com",
                        "Web: www.company.com",
                    ],
                },
                {
                    type: "none",
                    fontSize: 6,
                    margin: [0, 25, 0, 0],
                    ol: [
                        {
                            text: "ADDRES",
                            bold: true,
                        },
                        "Office 25B",
                        "Willowbrook Office Park",
                        "Van Hoof Street",
                        "Willowbrook, Roodepoort",
                        "1731",
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        { canvas: [{ type: "line", x1: 0, y1: 25, x2: 515, y2: 25, lineWidth: 3, color: "#D7DBDD" }] },
        {
            columns: [
                {
                    stack: [
                        { text: "CUSTOMER INFORMATION", bold: true, fontSize: 9 },
                        { text: dummyUser.firstName + " " + dummyUser.lastName, fontSize: 8 },
                        { text: "Code:" + " " + dummyUser.userCode, fontSize: 8 },
                        { text: "VAT No:" + " " + dummyUser.vatNumber, fontSize: 8 },
                        { text: "Tel:" + " " + dummyUser.numberPrime, fontSize: 8 },
                        { text: "Email:" + " " + dummyUser.emailPrime, fontSize: 8 },
                    ],
                    margin: [10, 20, 0, 0],
                    width: 150,
                },
                {
                    type: "none",
                    fontSize: 8,
                    margin: [0, 20, 0, 0],
                    width: 150,
                    ol: [
                        {
                            text: "CUSTOMER ADDRESS",
                            bold: true,
                            fontSize: 9,
                        },
                        "13 Wildeklawer",
                        "Welgevonden Estate",
                        "Stellenbosch",
                        "7600",
                    ],
                },
                {
                    type: "none",
                    fontSize: 8,
                    margin: [0, 15, 5, 0],
                    ol: [
                        {
                            text: "QUOTATION",
                            bold: true,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            alignment: "right",
                        },
                        {
                            style: "tableExample",
                            table: {
                                widths: [80, "*", "*", "*"],
                                heights: [15, 15, 15, 15],
                                body: [
                                    [
                                        { text: "QUOTATION NO", fontSize: 8 },
                                        { text: "CREATED", fontSize: 8 },
                                        { text: "DUE DATE", fontSize: 8 },
                                        { text: "TOTAL", fontSize: 8 },
                                    ],
                                    ["PRF1234", "31/03/2022", "31/03/2022", "R690.00"],
                                ],
                            },
                            layout: {
                                fillColor: function (rowIndex, node, columnIndex) {
                                    return rowIndex % 2 === 0 ? "#CCCCCC" : null;
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        { canvas: [{ type: "line", x1: 0, y1: 25, x2: 515, y2: 25, lineWidth: 3, color: "#D7DBDD" }] },

        {
            table: {
                headerRows: 1,
                widths: ["auto", "auto", "auto", "auto", "auto", "auto", "auto"],
                body: [
                    [
                        { text: "Service Type", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Service Item", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Qty", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Unit Price(VAT Incl)", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Discount", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Tax", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Total(VAT Incl)", style: "tableHeader" },
                    ],
                    dummyServiceData.map((data) => [data.serviceType, data.service, data.quantity.toString(), data.price.toString(), data.discount.toString(), data.total.toString()]),
                ],
            },
        },
    ],
    styles: {
        header: {
            fontSize: 18,
            bold: true,
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 10],
        },
        subheader: {
            fontSize: 16,
            bold: true,
            margin: [0, 10, 0, 5],
        },
        tableExample: {
            margin: [0, 5, 0, 15],
        },
        tableHeader: {
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 8,
            color: "white",
            fillColor: "black",
        },
    },
    defaultStyle: {
        // alignment: 'justify'
    },
};
```

With the dummydata I try to map through it, but I get an error stating that *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_calcWidth')* Now as I understand, I have set the amount of columns correctly (7) and yet I'm not winning. Can someone please assist me in showing what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you so much in advance.

Here is how the table should look once it has been completed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it is taking whole dummyServiceData as a single row. I was facing similar issue then I did it like this:

```
       const bodyData: any[] = [];

       // Here change bodyColumns to your column array
       bodyData.push(bodyColumns);

       // Here change bodyRowsData to your dummyServiceData array And then assign this body to your table body, do mapping or what ever other thing you want on dummyServiceData  before it 
       const body = bodyData.concat(bodyRowsData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by doing the following:

```
    function setColumns(data) {
    let tableData = [];
    for (const d of data) {
        tableData.push([
            { text: d.serviceType },
            { text: d.service },
            { text: d.quantity },
            { text: "R " + d.price.toFixed(2) },
            { text: "R " + d.discount.toFixed(2) },
            { text: 0 },
            { text: "R " + d.total.toFixed(2) },
        ]);
    }
    return tableData;
}

let columns = setColumns(dummyServiceData);
```

and then you explode the array

```
{
            style: "defaultTable",
            table: {
                headerRows: 1,
                widths: [55, 180, "*", 75, 45, "*", 70],
                heights: 30,

                body: [
                    [
                        { text: "Service Type", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Service Item", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Qty", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Unit Price(VAT Incl)", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Discount", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Tax", style: "tableHeader" },
                        { text: "Total(VAT Incl)", style: "tableHeader" },
                    ],

                    ...columns,
                ],
            },
            layout: "lightHorizontalLines",
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

With the @Niishaw answer I made something like that to dynamically create a Table from the array:

```
var aKeys = Object.keys(dummyServiceData[0]);
var transformedData = dummyServiceData.map(
    function(icurrentValue) {
        return Object.values(icurrentValue);
        }
);
transformedData.unshift(aKeys);
```

or you can add some style:

```
var transformedData = dummyServiceData.map(
    function(icurrentValue) {
        return Object.values(icurrentValue).map(
            function(jcurrentValue, jindex) {
                    return {text: icurrentValue[aKeys[jindex]], style:'tableText1'}
                        });
                
        }
);
```

and in the content:

```
 table: {
                headerRows: 1,
                heights: 18,
                body: [
                  ...transformedData,
                ],
            },
```